# Unable to test in app purchase in my BlackBerry Playbook

Tags: apache-flex, in-app-purchase, blackberry-10, blackberry-playbook

I have updated a sample test application in BlackBerry Vendor portal to test the in app purchase and I hold the application in draft.
Now when I check with my BlackBerry Playbook to get the sample application, I get an  "internal server error".

I've read ["How To: Live Testing the Payment SDK with PlayBook Applications"](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-World-Development/How-To-Live-Testing-the-Payment-SDK-with-PlayBook-Applications/ta-p/1749859), and I used `http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/myblackberryid` to open the sample application in my playbook.